# jQuery datatables : Disable chechbox except the checked checbox with pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery data tables in which there are something 13000 user records with checkbox option.

As the requirement, I can select any 3 users from them by selecting the checkbox option against that particular users.

When I reach the limit i.e. 3 all other checkbox option should get disable.

But the currently, it work only for that particular page. When I select the 3 users from page 1 then all other checkbox options gets disabled but when I move to second page then all the options are available to select the users. Means, it works correctly but as per the page wise.

I don't want this, it should work as I reach the limit i.e. 3 all other checkbox option should get disable across all the pages.

**jQuery Code :**  Where checkb is class name for all checkbox. Also, I have attached the image for more information.

```
if($('input.checkb').filter(':checked').length == 3)
        $('input.checkb:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     else
        $('input.checkb').removeAttr('disabled');
```

[image]

Comment: How do you "move" to the next page - through post or AJAX call?

Comment: it's jQuery datatables...I don't know which method they are using for moving across pages.

Comment: try to put code in jsfiddle so its easy to give solution

Comment: [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/07Lrpqm7/428/) here you can see the solution

Answer (score 0):

With **JQuery 1.6+** you should use the .prop() function.

```
if($('input.checkb').filter(':checked').length == 3)
   $('input.checkb:not(:checked)').prop('disabled', true);
else
   $('input.checkb').prop('disabled', false);
```

UPDATE: let say your data table object is `datatable` you can use like this

```
  var rows = datatable.rows().nodes();
  $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)', rows).prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Sorry..but it's not working..same issue raised again :(

Comment: Attribute parameter does not work across all the pages. Same for prop function, it does not work across all the pages.

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this is ,
You can send an ajax request to server to set a session variable in server,
When each time user checks the checkbox these request should call to increment the session variable. When the count becomes 3 you can check this with all pages for disabling or enabling the check boxes in the list.

Another option is set the checkbox checked count in a hidden box in that page and make the entire paging to ajax. So you can check the hidden box count in every page with javascript for enabling and disabling check boxes.